# Dynamodb local web shell not displaying tables

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-local

I have set up dynamodb docker image with the following command:

```
$ docker run -p 8000:8000 -v /Users/me/test/:/data/ amazon/dynamodb-local -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar --sharedDb --dbPath /data
```

I am able to create a table:

```
$ aws dynamodb create-table --table-name aaa --attribute-definitions AttributeName=id,AttributeType=S --key-schema AttributeName=id,KeyType=HASH --billing-mode PAY_PER_REQUEST  --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

I am able to list the tables using aws cli:

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

But when I use localhost:8000/shell to listTables, I get an empty list. What is the correct way to display the tables on the shell?

Answer (score 0):

turns out I was copying the listTables code from the shell and forgot to remove `ExclusiveStartTableName: 'table_name',` value from the function

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues but mine is the difference of two regions in my ~/.aws/config

Even dynamodb-local separates regions.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I was having the same issue.. turns out I used two different 'fakeAwsAccessKeyId' values (one in my unit tests, a different one from the command line). Once I looked at the folder I saw the two .db files and realized my error.